# Why trimToSize/ensureCapacity methods provide 'public' level access?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, abstraction

Any user who would like to access the `java.util.ArrayList` facility,  has to obey the usage contract provided in `java.util.List`.

But one can break this usage contract easily and access the methods `trimToSize`

```
public void trimToSize() { ... }
```

and `ensureCapacity`

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) { ...}
```

Because these two methods are neither overridden from `java.util.AbstractList` nor implemented from `java.util.List`.

So, Why these two methods provide `public` level access and  break the abstraction provided by `java.util.List`?

Comment: These methods are additional functionality.  I don't think they break any contract in `java.util.List`, as all of that functionality is also (presumably) correctly implemented.  In what way do you think they break the contract?

Comment: In what way is the abstraction provided by `java.util.List` "broken" by these `ArrayList` methods? That's kind of like saying that dogs "break the abstraction of 'mammal'" because they can bark, while barking is not part of the abstraction "mammal".

Comment: So you're saying that subclasses should never be able to extend the interface of their super classes with public methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: @TedHopp  Here the abstraction separates interface(`List`) from implementation(`ArrayList`/`LinkedList`). Purpose of this abstraction is to access the list facility via interface(`List`) only. Am I correct?

Comment: The purpose of the abstraction is to specify a contract of behavior that all `List` implementations must provide. Implementation classes are free to add behavior beyond that specified in the contract. If one knows that an object is a specific implementation type, nothing is "broken" by using that extra behavior. It is a different question, however, to ask if _using_ those extra methods violates the ["interface-based programming"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming) architectural pattern or "program to the interface" advice. It does. But the methods themselves don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some cases where efficiency may cost more than data abstraction. The `ensureCapacity` may be used to preallocate the internal buffer once when you are about to add known number of elements. The `trimToSize` may be used when you are not going to add more elements to free wasted memory. Both methods are non-applicable to other `List` implementations, thus they are added to `ArrayList` only.

Note that usually list is created and initially populated by one method which knows what implementation is used. So this does not break abstraction. For example, consider such code:

```
public List<String> createList() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // populate the list
    list.trimToSize();
    return list;
}
```

This way you can save the memory and still return the `List` interace.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing here breaks `List`'s contract. `ArrayList` is a specific implementation of `List`, and if your program has specific performance needs that are important enough for you to forgo the abstraction of using a `List`, there's no reason not to allow you to use specific methods to tune `ArrayList`'s behavior.